# I have to toggle ethernet off/on to get online every restart

Tags: ethernet

I have an Ubuntu VM.  After installing the most recent Ubuntu update (16.04 I think?), every time I boot up the VM the system cannot get online and browse the internet.  I have to go to System Preferences and disable/re-enable ethernet and this quick 'refresh' gets me back online.

Whats causing this?

Comment: I also have this problem. When I was in VirtualBox 5.1, every Ubuntu VM that I have created connected online using the "integrated" ethernet card with no tweaks in the system or things like that. However, when I upgraded to VirtualBox 5.2, every Ubuntu VM tries to connect to a Wi-Fi network and refreshes all time, no matter how many times I click on "eth0" on the drop-down menu. Probably the new VirtualBox Guest Additions are somehow buggy.

Answer (score 1):

There is a file in your home directory called `.profile`.

The above post recommends you add a line to it (`ifup eth1`) which enables your network card.
You could also add a line before that (`ifdown eth0`) which would shut down your network card.
This would in theory simulate what you are doing in the guitar.
Essentially it's a script or batch file that will run that command at boot which in theory is the same as disabling and enabling your network card that you are doing to make your network work.

It's a workaround not a solution for why it's happening but it will make your virtual machine function on boot up.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line to the `~/.profile` file:

```
ifup eth1
```

To do this, open the file (which you can find in your home directory in your file browser by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) with a text editor such as gedit, add the line to the end, save and exit.

This will cause the command `ifup eth1` to be run every time you log in (or start a login shell).

Comment: I have no idea what that means, sorry :(

Comment: It will put your ethernet on every time you login. See Andreas Tyrosvoutis's post, he explained it little bit more.

Comment: Could you please expand the answer a bit more so that even new users can apply the fix following the suggestions provided?